# C# counting repeating numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, random, messagebox

I need a way to find and count the repeating numbers of this RNG.

So when I press the button like 500 times it need to count the times the same number apeared any ideas ?  (Build in Visial Studio 2017 C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Alpha_rng
{
public partial class RNG : Form
{
    private int number;
    public RNG()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int tal { get; private set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random(); 
        int tal;
        tal = slumpGenerator.Next(0, 1000);
        textBox1.Text = tal.ToString();
        if (tal <=  10)
            MessageBox.Show ("Nat 5");
        if (tal >= 11 && tal <= 100) 
            MessageBox.Show("Nat 4");
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("Nat 3");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too general and you have not explained what it is you cannot do or what approaches you have tried and had problems with.

Comment: It should automaticly count the repeating number that appear after i pressed the button if lets say after 5 presses i get the same number it should count the times it happend and also write down the number lets say 134 repeting count 3 12 repeating counts 2 i cant figure it out how i can be that speciffic

Comment: GhostCat solution worked flawlesly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

- create an empty list
- during each loop: store the random number in that list

And then; either during each iteration; or after your 500 runs: iterate that list; and look for the information you need. You could for example sort the list; and then see if you have "sublists" with the same value.

Creating a list can be as easy as:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
```

See [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list) for examples on lists.

Beyond that; you could of course use "advanced" things; such as maps. The map key represents the random value; and the map value would be a counter. In other words: you draw a number; and then you check that map. If the map already has an entry, you simply increase that counter; if not; you add a value of 1 for that key. That is more efficient compared to sorting/iterating a list of values!

Comment: Oh my sounds like a simple solution over thinking at its finest thanks gonna try it out.

Comment: Thank you damn it kinda bothers me that I over complicated something that simple you just saved me a lot of frustration time.

Comment: would be easier ? 
    var numberList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList()

Comment: Well, that would fill your list with the values I guess. But what is the point of doing that, when you intend to **count** how often random numbers show up?

Comment: Oh yeh true ok im gonna try the stuff out now and gonna give a lill feedback if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

static int count = 0;

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

{ 

   count++; 

   messagebox.show(count);

}
```

Comment: `static`? **Why?**

Comment: we can use it anywhere you just try this

Comment: Choosing `static` by default is a bad practice. If you create two instances, both forms will share the count field which makes it impossible to reuse the form. _" 
we can use it anywhere"_ you mean when you're creating it public.

Comment: OK,but i hope it is your solution.you just try without static also it will work

Comment: Too bad, the question is not about counting the button clicks.